# JMS onMessage ByteMessage write to PDF file

Tags: spring, jms, byte

I have a Spring JMS listener that receives a BytesMessage/JMSBytesMessage.
I want to convert this message into a PDF file and write it onto a drive.

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {

BytesMessage bmsg = (BytesMessage) message;

ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


}
```

I know I need to do something like msg.readBytes, but I am having trouble putting everything together...could someone offer some hints.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something simple like this should work:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
   try {
      BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) message;

      // copy data into a byte[] buffer
      int dataSize = (int) bytesMessage.getBodyLength();
      byte[] buffer = new byte[dataSize];
      bytesMessage.readBytes(buffer, dataSize);

      // now write the buffer to a file
      File outputFile = new File("/path/to/file.pdf");
      FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
      try {
         fileOutput.write(buffer);
      } finally {
         fileOutput.close();
      }
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      // handle exception
   }
}
```

This should work fine as long as the data size isn't very large.

Comment: Anything over 10Mb and you may need to configure the JMS provider, I know SonicMQ rejects messages larger than 10Mb, just something to keep in mind.